# Selecting Table TDs by range using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this table,

```
    | A   | B   | C   | D   | E   | F   |
-----------------------------------------
1   |     |10/09|11/09|12/09|13/09|14/09|
2   |Joy  |Fail |     |Pass |     |Fail |
3   |Jay  |     |Pass |Fail |     |Pass |
4   |John |Fail |     |Pass |Fail |     |
5   |Jess |Fail |Pass |Pass |Fail |Fail |
```

I want to get the TDs from range A:2 - A:4. The A:2 - A:4 is the value input from user. So sometimes it can be B:2 - B:6 or other range.

I have this code,

```
var l = parseInt($("#dd2").val())+2;
            var f = parseInt($("#dd1").val())+1;
            for(var f2 = f; f2<l;f2++){
                $("#table table tbody tr:lt("+f2+"):gt("+(f2-2)+")").children().eq(1).css("border-top","3px solid gray").css("border-left","3px solid gray");
            }
```

Where dd1 is the first row (in the example, it is row 2), and dd2 is the last row (in the example, it is row 4). 
What I have done with the code above is get the First column only. So it does not select other TDs from other columns.

Also, I need also the code to handle if the range is from columns like, B:2 - F:2.

Comment: and also, the length of columns or row is unknown. It is dynamic. Thanks.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scratched my head a little on your question.

It was quite unclear at first. But I think I understood what your want.
Have a look at my [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/kkEGjY?editors=1010).

When you click on a date, the column hightlights.
When you click on a student name, the row hightlights.

If Pass, the cell is green.
If Fail, the cell is red.
If the student was absent, the cell is yellow.

**Script**

```
$(".student").click(function(){

    // Reset
    $(".result").css({"background":"none","border":"1px solid black"});

    // Select a row
    $(this).siblings(".result").css({"border-top":"2px double black","border-bottom":"2px double black"});
    $(this).siblings(".result").each(function(){
        if( $(this).html() == "Fail" ){
            $(this).css("background","red");
        }else if( $(this).html() == "Pass" ){
            $(this).css("background","green");
        }else{
            $(this).css("background","yellow");
        }
    });
});

$(".date").click(function(){
    var thisRowis = $(this).index();

    // Reset
    $(".result").css({"background":"none","border":"1px solid black"});

    // Select a column
    $(".student").each(function(){
        var thisDate = $(this).siblings(".result").eq(thisRowis-2);
        thisDate.css({"border-left":"2px double black","border-right":"2px double black"});
        if( thisDate.html() == "Fail" ){
            thisDate.css("background","red");
        }else if( thisDate.html() == "Pass" ){
            thisDate.css("background","green");
        }else{
            thisDate.css("background","yellow");
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="col">A</th>
        <th class="col">B</th>
        <th class="col">C</th>
        <th class="col">D</th>
        <th class="col">E</th>
        <th class="col">F</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th class="date">10/09</th>
        <th class="date">11/09</th>
        <th class="date">12/09</th>
        <th class="date">13/09</th>
        <th class="date">14/09</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="row">1</th>
        <td class="student">Joy</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
        <td class="result">Pass</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="row">2</th>
        <td class="student">Jay</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
        <td class="result">Pass</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
        <td class="result">Pass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="row">3</th>
        <td class="student">John</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
        <td class="result">Pass</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <th class="row">4</th>
        <td class="student">Jess</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
        <td class="result">Pass</td>
        <td class="result">Pass</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
        <td class="result">Fail</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```